# Do roads count as improvements for Weather Controller Sats?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

Weather Controllers Generate 1 to 2 new Basic Resources on unimproved tiles across its lifespan.

Do Roads/Magrail count as improvements for this purpose?

Comment: I don't think roads/magrails count, since they can be built on top of, and thus coexist with, other improvements. But I cannot confirm it's interaction with weather controllers because I've yet to use that satellite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magrails do NOT count as improvements for Orbital Fabricators which are basically the same thing as weather controllers, except they generate Strategic Resources instead of Basic Resources. Seems likely you can build roads/mag under your weather sats too!
[image]